# TypeError: get_token() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bs4'

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i wanted to grab a token from a website this is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class checker_start(object):
    def get_token(self, bs4):
        data = requests.get("https://login.live.com")
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'lxml')

        token_1 = soup.find("input", {"value": "flowToken"})["value"]
        return token_1


print(checker_start().get_token())
```

however i get this error:

```
TypeError: get_token() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bs4'
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you need to pass bs4 argument to the Class. 
bs4 is already imported. you can try this to get the job done

```
    def get_token(self):
        data = requests.get("https://login.live.com")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'lxml')

        token_1 = soup.find("input", {"value": "flowToken"})["value"]
        return token_1


print(checker_start().get_token())
```